# BigQuery or something else for a CRUD App

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, crud

I need to make updates to about 10-20 records in bigquery on a monthly basis.
These records are stores that have closed down.

Most of my data is currently in bigquery, but I'm wondering, would it make sense for me to continue using bigquery for this crud app, or branch off into another database and then sync them?

Comment: For this small number of updates, you can definitely choose to go with BigQuery. How big is your dataset that you need to scan before updating the records?

Comment: Max of 3000 records.

Comment: It should be fine.

Comment: Be careful to latency. Not designed for low latency website.